# TypeError: Unhashable type numpy.ndarray on pivot_table

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table

Hope you can help on this. I've been cracking my head to figure this out. I have the following pandas dataframe, df.info below:

```
DatetimeIndex: 18135 entries, 2019-09-20 14:32:02 to 2019-07-29 10:13:07
Data columns (total 10 columns):
OrderNo           18135 non-null object
HasDiscrepency    18135 non-null object
CreatedDate       18135 non-null datetime64[ns]
ExportedDate      18135 non-null datetime64[ns]
ExportedBy        18135 non-null object
XDStr             18135 non-null object
XMStr             18135 non-null object
V2X               18135 non-null timedelta64[ns]
V2Xt              18135 non-null float64
AutoExported      18135 non-null bool
dtypes: bool(1), datetime64[ns](2), float64(1), object(5), timedelta64[ns](1)
```

Sample data from it:

```
{'OrderNo': {Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:32:02'): '225-191369-0',
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:20:38'): 'OrderOne',
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:33:39'): 'OrderTwo',
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:11:32'): '30462951',
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:11:09'): '259257',
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:58:50'): 'ABC12345',
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:44:32'): '82/02357',
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:43:31'): '05/077228',
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:31:11'): 'DEF456',
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:31:01'): '6425V1874720G'},
 'HasDiscrepency': {Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:32:02'): array(False),
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:20:38'): array(True),
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:33:39'): array(True),
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:11:32'): array(False),
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:11:09'): array(False),
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:58:50'): array(True),
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:44:32'): array(False),
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:43:31'): array(True),
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:31:11'): array(False),
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:31:01'): array(False)},
 'CreatedDate': {Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:32:02'): Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:31:29'),
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:20:38'): Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:17:17'),
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:33:39'): Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:14:58'),
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:11:32'): Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:10:23'),
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:11:09'): Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:07:16'),
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:58:50'): Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:57:47'),
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:44:32'): Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:44:20'),
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:43:31'): Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:36:59'),
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:31:11'): Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:31:03'),
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:31:01'): Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:26:21')},
 'ExportedDate': {Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:32:02'): Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:32:02'),
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:20:38'): Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:20:38'),
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:33:39'): Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:33:39'),
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:11:32'): Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:11:32'),
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:11:09'): Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:11:09'),
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:58:50'): Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:58:50'),
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:44:32'): Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:44:32'),
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:43:31'): Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:43:31'),
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:31:11'): Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:31:11'),
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:31:01'): Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:31:01')},
 'ExportedBy': {Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:32:02'): 'UserA',
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:20:38'): 'UserB',
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:33:39'): 'UserA',
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:11:32'): 'UserD',
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:11:09'): 'UserD',
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:58:50'): 'UserD',
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:44:32'): 'UserD',
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:43:31'): 'UserF',
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:31:11'): 'UserG',
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:31:01'): 'UserG'},
 'XDStr': {Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:32:02'): '2019-09-20',
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:20:38'): '2019-09-20',
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:33:39'): '2019-09-20',
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:11:32'): '2019-09-20',
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:11:09'): '2019-09-20',
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:58:50'): '2019-09-20',
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:44:32'): '2019-09-20',
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:43:31'): '2019-09-20',
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:31:11'): '2019-09-20',
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:31:01'): '2019-09-20'},
 'XMStr': {Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:32:02'): '2019 09',
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:20:38'): '2019 09',
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:33:39'): '2019 09',
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:11:32'): '2019 09',
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:11:09'): '2019 09',
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:58:50'): '2019 09',
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:44:32'): '2019 09',
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:43:31'): '2019 09',
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:31:11'): '2019 09',
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:31:01'): '2019 09'},
 'V2X': {Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:32:02'): Timedelta('0 days 00:00:17'),
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:20:38'): Timedelta('0 days 00:03:00'),
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:33:39'): Timedelta('0 days 00:02:43'),
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:11:32'): Timedelta('0 days 00:00:12'),
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:11:09'): Timedelta('0 days 00:00:20'),
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:58:50'): Timedelta('0 days 00:00:51'),
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:44:32'): Timedelta('0 days 00:00:08'),
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:43:31'): Timedelta('0 days 00:02:16'),
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:31:11'): Timedelta('0 days 00:00:08'),
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:31:01'): Timedelta('0 days 00:04:40')},
 'V2Xt': {Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:32:02'): 17.0,
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:20:38'): 180.0,
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:33:39'): 163.0,
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:11:32'): 12.0,
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:11:09'): 20.0,
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:58:50'): 51.0,
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:44:32'): 8.0,
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:43:31'): 136.0,
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:31:11'): 8.0,
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:31:01'): 280.0},
 'AutoExported': {Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:32:02'): False,
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:20:38'): False,
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:33:39'): False,
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:11:32'): False,
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 14:11:09'): False,
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:58:50'): False,
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:44:32'): False,
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:43:31'): False,
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:31:11'): True,
  Timestamp('2019-09-20 13:31:01'): True}}
```

`XMStr` and `XDStr` are dates formatted as strings to help with my reports. Both are based on the ExpDate index.
`V2X` is a timedelta while `V2Xt` is `V2X` formatted as float.
`HasDiscrepency` is a True/False value

From this data, I'm trying to run the following. It's supposed to generate a report of the average of V2Xt per Month, split into HasDiscrepency (Y or N):

```
v2x_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df['2019-07-29':'2019-09-20'],
                           index=['XMStr'],
                           columns=['HasDiscrepency'],
                           values=['V2Xt'],
                           margins=True,
                           aggfunc=[np.mean])
```

But I'm running into this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
...
pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.factorize()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable._unique()

TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Any ideas how to resolve this? Do I need to change anything in my columns?

Comment: are you able to copy/paste a small textual example of your dataframe,

Comment: @Datanovice, added as requested. Thanks!

Comment: might be me being daft, but i can't get your columns to line up, can you print `df.head(5).to_dict()` and paste it here?

Comment: No worries @Datanovice, that actually helped get some insight. Something might have happened to my HasDiscrepency column to be processed as `array(True)` instead of jut boolean values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert values to list and then to array and ressign back:

```
df['HasDiscrepency'] = pd.array(df['HasDiscrepency'].tolist())
```

Then removed `[]` for avoid `MultiIndex` in columns:

```
v2x_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df['2019-07-29':'2019-09-20'],
                           index='XMStr',
                           columns='HasDiscrepency',
                           values='V2Xt',
                           margins=True,
                           aggfunc=np.mean)
print (v2x_pivot)
HasDiscrepency  False   True   All
XMStr                             
2019 09          57.5  132.5  87.5
All              57.5  132.5  87.5
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael. Giving credit to @Datanovice as well for leading the way with the `to_dict` method. Cheers!

Comment: May not work if the column has list as values in it, in this case you can iterate as a quick solution.